# want to retrive every visible and clickable view on the screen from another app,including itemviews of recyclerView using accessibility service

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

My question is I want to retrive every visible and clickable view on the screen with their position,including itemviews of recyclerView using accessibility service and their positions on screen.

I have configured accessibilityService as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged|
                                     typeWindowStatChanged"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
android:canPerformGestures="true"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
/>
```

but I am not getting every visible view on screen.Is there any other way to get all view visible on screen??

Comment: There's no code here. How are you fetching the content? Presumably getRootInActiveWindow()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do note my comment on missing the code that you're utilizing to actually look at the node hierarchy. That being said, if you truly want to see ALL views, you're xml configuration is missing a flag.

I recommend replacing this line:

```
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
```

With the following:

```
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
```

Comment: Hey Chris..thanks for your reply..now i am actually able to retrive all nodes.But currently getting new issue with accessibility service.If my currently open window has some hyperlink and if my service calls getRootInActiveWindow() then sytem again firing event and OnAccessibilityEvent method gets called and this loop will run infinitely..It stops only when i change content on screen by scrolling or any otherway and new content does not have any hyperlink in its view..can you please guide me on this problem..Again thanks for using your valuable time to solve my problem..